# Is there a way to report the file name of a imported dataset?

Tags: r, excel, filenames

I'm trying to set up a export to .xlsx file that will include the name of the dataset into its title.

I have the functions and everything fine to add objects into the title and export it, but I dont know report the name of my original dataset as an object which I can then add into the function.

(Using Rstudio 1.3)
Before analysing my data, I import the dataset, "DS". I then call this "input".

```
input <- DS
data("input")
```

After all analysis is done, I set up the name I want to append and call it "name". I made it to include the row name, column name, and then a .xlsx at the end to save it as a .xlsx file (it was just saving without file extension before that)

```
name <- paste(analysis.score$pairs$row, 
                  analysis.score$pairs$column, 
                     ".xlsx", sep = "_") 

write.xlsx(analysis.score, name)
```

My resulting file will be something like "row_column_.xlsx"

What I need is a command to report what the file name of the dataset is (in this example DS), so that I can include it into the name to paste onto the file.

I've tried using `name(input)`  but it returnns the names of all the columns in the file.
I have a number of datasets to analyse, and would like it so that I just have to put each dataset title in once at the begining of the script.

Sorry if this doesnt make sense, I'm *very* new to this (started Monday)

Thanks!

Comment: I dont actually use a code for the import, I use the "Import Dataset" function in RStudio to import the file into the Global Environment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an importing function that saves as an attribute to the data the file name that holds the data outside of R.  That said, it would be pretty easy to make one.

```
my_import <- function(filename, ...){
  require(rio)
  require(stringr)
  x <- import(filename, ...)
  ## strip off leading absolute or relative path information
  attr(x, "filename") <- str_extract(filename, "[\\w\\d\\.\\_\\-]*$")
  return(x)
}
```

Then, as long as you have the `rio` and `stringr` packages installed, you would be able to do the following:

```
df <- my_import("my_file.xlsx")
attr(df, "filename")
# [1] "my_file.xlsx"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm using RStudios built-in import dataset function as I have a lot of datasets to run and they're all in different directories, but I tried using some of the code you wrote but it doesn't seem to be returning exactly what I need.
What does this variable do?? : ` "[\\w\\d\\.\\_\\-]*$" `

Also, I managed to find this code 

`name_of_df <- ls.str(mode = "list")
  name_of_df[1]`

This is giviing me what I need, but it requires that my dataframe is the first in the environment.

Comment: That part would extract everything that's the combination of letters, digits, periods, underscores and semicolons before the end of the string.  The idea was, if the file name was "~/Documents/file-13.sav", that you would only want to return  "file-13.sav".  Thats what the string would do.   Are you trying to find the name of the data object in R or the name of the file from which the data object in R was made?

Comment: @Kmast Also, if you've got lots of files and directories, it might be easier to come up with a programmatic way of reading the data in rather than using the RStudio import function.